# What is the best way to style in css?

Tags: css, conventions

I read through [this](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) (this is a post from css-tricks.com), and [this](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors#comment_3942) (this one is a comment to a post).

This is how my css looks:

```
.m0 { margin : 0%;          }   //m0 = Margin 0% <br>
.mla { margin-left  : auto; }   //mla = Margin Left Auto <br>
.mra { margin-right : auto; }   //mra = Margin Right Auto

.w100px { width : 1000px; }   //w1000px = Width 1000px

.h100 { height : 100%; }   //h100 = Height 100%
```

etc..

I use my css only with classes, like this:

```
<html class="h100">   <!-- Height 100% -->,

<body class="m0 h100">   <!-- Margin 0%, Height 100% -->, 

<div class="mla mra w1000px">   <!-- Margin-Left Auto, Margin-Right Auto, Width 1000px-->
```

etc...

If I want to create a red page using only the body my classes would look like this:

**CSS**

```
.m0 { margin : 0%; }

.bc08070 { background-color : hsl(0, 80%, 70%); }
//bgi = Background Color (hsl) 0 80% 70%
```

**HTML**

```
<body class="m0 bc08070"> <!-- Margin 0%, Background Color (hsl) 0 80% 70% -->
```

I write the class names in the order I wrote the css in: Margin (first), Width (next), Height (after that), Background Color (after that).

This way I don't rewrite any code and if I need to add a css attribute I can just add the appropriate class, I feel I have much better control this way.

Is this the best convention in css in terms of efficiency?

If it's not, please go into great depth on the best convention so that I understand what convention I'm using, and more importantly, why I'm using it.

Comment: This is possibly the worst CSS I've ever seen. You're strictly coupling meaning and presentation, which you shouldn't. That's the point of having CSS separated.
What if you want to change one of the properties? Right, you need to edit the HTML, the classname and the property itself.

Comment: `margin : 0%` is oft considered bad practice - the number 0 doesn't have any dimensions anyway, so adding `%`, `px` or `em` to it doesn't make a difference. It's thus usually written as `margin:0`.

Comment: @Prinzhorn I've seen sites that advertised having a 'totally table free layout', instead containing `<div class="table"><div class="row"><div class="cell">`. That's comparable ;)

Comment: @Prinzhorn, you think my css is the worst because if I want to change one of the properties I have to rename the property through-out my html? I can do that with one RegExp, what is meaning and presentation?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, thank you for the helpful tip, but how is the css itself?

Comment: @Oscar What you are doing is basically misusing the `class` attribute the way the `style` attribute was used. "I can do that with one RegExp": the point of a separate CSS file is that you don't have to do it at all. Why not use `html` and `body` selector? Why not give the `div` a class called `wrapper` and center it?

Comment: @Prinzhorn, The style attribute is very inefficient, I still don't understand "Meaning and presentation." I don't mind using the RegExp it takes a few seconds and I rarely have to change class names. I don't make a #wrapper because I have to write "margin : 0px auto" and I will have to write "margin : 0px auto" everytime I want to centre a div, so I write "mla mra" in the div class name instead.

Comment: I must agree with @Prinzhorn here. BTW In what way is the style attribute inefficient?

Comment: @Oscar the difference between presentation and meaning is the difference between a class called `header` and `bigFontAndBlueBackground`. One describes **what** it is and the other **how** it should look like. You should structure your CSS based on what the elements mean. This is not always possible, but your approach just breaks with every rule and is hardly readable.

Comment: @chaz2041, It's only inefficient in ie7<, that's why I don't use it, am I wrong here? Chaz could you write me up an answer that really explains how you use your css techniques and why? The more the merrier, right?

Comment: I changed your question and used code blocks instead of quote blocks. Code is a bit easier to read in a monospaced font.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, Thanks man - that's what I wanted to know!

Comment: I would like to point out that this question is a not a very good fit for this site. If you read the faq it clearly states that you should avoid certain questions under the [What should I not ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). This is one of those "What do you use" types of questions. I don't think anyone will close the question, but you should try to ask questions that has "one" answer in the future, so moderators won't close it.

Comment: @Patrick, i'll sure do that, but I believe this question is also one of those "What am I doing wrong" questions, I also ask this: "Is this the best convention in css?" After I explain the convention that i'm using.

Comment: Asking what the "best" is is *very* subjective. Not only do people consider different things the best, but you're not stating what it is best *in*. Is it best considering reusability, is it best in simplicity to use, is it best if you are creating a mars rover and it should parse your css in space. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Patrick, I see what your saying, I added "in terms of efficiency" to my question. In which case Niels answer is the correct one - because it accounts for SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code defeats the entire point of what the separation of HTML and CSS has done for the web development world. If you are going to embed your styling in the HTML anyway, you could just use `style="width:1000px"` attributes instead of `class="w100px"` for the exact same effect, or go back to good ole 1999-style HTML 3.2 with `<font>` and `<color>` tags. We didn't ditch those tags without reason in the 21st century, because that's why we have **separate** CSS files nowadays.

The whole point is to assign classes and IDs by their ***semantic meaning***, describing the **content**, not the **presentation**. The HTML should be completely machine readable, without any assumption about rendering media, specifically not a 'screen'. Your HTML should be 100% clear and obvious to a braille reader, a screen reader, a search engine, without ***any single reference*** to layout.

So instead of:

```
<div class="w100px m10px">
  My content
</div>
```

You should use:

```
<article class="main">
  My content
</article>
```

As you can see the HTML is now completely devoid of *how you want it to look*, it just contains *the content you're presenting*. And then you style it with:

```
article.main {
  width:1000px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

You should definitely go read some tutorials about [the Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) though, and forget nearly everything you've learned so far - sorry to say that.

Comment: Um, hey Niels are you suggesting that I use more style tags? It appears the semantic web is not fully supported - is that true?

Comment: I am definitely ***NOT*** in any way suggesting to use more style tags. Your HTML should not include ***ANY*** reference to layout, widths, margins, colors, whatever, unless **absolutely** required and you have very good reason to do so.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes try removing any sarcasm as this may confuse novice developers

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks! I'm going to read more into "Less" and the semantic web before I mark a question right - so @Prinzhorn do you have any further suggestions you can wrap into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I only use generic/reusable classes for stuff like wrappers, page columns and basic stuff like inputs, buttons, links.

About naming convention is often better to have more descriptive class names. I usually use the "page name", let's say I'm doing something for a registration page `.register-save-button`. So basically the pattern is `.{page}-{what}-{it}-{is}

The thing with naming is also that if you want to have a carrier and work for a company, as a professional or in a team, your naming convention is not gone work for other developers to understand. I always try to write html/css/javascripts/code with a "team mind state".

Your css also does not look good and does not seem effective, its nothing would allow any new team member to use.

If you don't want to repeat yourself on colors and what not you should look into [LESS](http://lesscss.org) styling.

Comment: Wow thanks Dejan, i'm really going to inspect less to check for cross-browser compatibility, thanks a lot for the explanation on naming - but are you agreeing that the reusable class-name thing works for some things?

Comment: Your welcome. Sure to a certain extend, for example. In this project I'm working on we got 3 different styles of buttons, so we got 3 classes and reuse those. I need to point out that reusable as in you do I would do for maybe this cause `.pull-left {float: left;}` and `.pull-right {float: left;}`

Comment: Ah I see, it appears less is fully cross-browser compatible, s i'll now read through the documentation on some the functionality.

Comment: Hey Dejan, Less looks a bit complex for me at the moment. I think we should hand this over to Niels because he explains the correct conventions for the future of the web, which is the direction I may as well accept I should also go in.