# best way to write CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi am creating a website, I am a bit confused about how to write CSS..
I want to whether I should used different classes for same style of should I make style specific class and used them every where... let me use an example...

suppose I want to give a min height, should I use this:

```
.div1,.div2,.div3{min-height:335px;}
```

and use HTML like this:

```
<div class="div1">afads</div>
<div class="div2">fads</div>
<div class="div3">fads</div>
```

or should I do it like this:
CSS:

```
.minheightstyle{min-height:225px;}
.leftitems{float:left;}
.red{background-color:red;}
.blue{background-color:blue;}
.grey{background-color:grey;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="minheightstyle leftitems red">my text in red bg</div>
<div class="minheightstyle leftitems blue">my text in blue bg</div>
<div class="minheightstyle leftitems grey">my text in grey bg</div>
```

which way is the best way to optimized way and which one should i use,
does it matter.

Comment: I'm not sure why your receiving downvotes, this is actually a very good question.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045448/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-css-not-learn-but-really-use

Comment: Please read my answer here for a thorough reading on why `.red` is an evil way of styling - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16776592/1729885

Comment: This is both non-constructive and duplicate. Besides, the question uses very poor class names, and using descriptive class names (rather than names for very specific styling) would be more important than the question asked (which is vague, too – “not a real question”).

Answer (score 7):

I would do neither. I wouldn't do the first, because that's what classes are for if elements have the same styles.

I wouldn't do the latter because that defeats the purpose of styles if you are going to make custom classes for every style item. Consider the following:

```
<div class="font-size color margin text padding float-left">some div</div>
```

In the above it comes scary close to just using inline CSS. To change the look of the above you would need to change the actual HTML instead of simply the class.

I would rather create a generic class e.g. `article` with the styling of an article instead of saying `class="font-verdana margin color"` etc. Maybe for the color you might have a point because you want to use different colors for the three `div` but in general those three `div`s should have the same class.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it does not matter as both will work the same.

However the goal should be to make your css clear, re-usable and ideally minimal, and you should target your selectors and rules to show this.

Certain rules like backgrounds and colours will usually only apply to a specific element. For that reason you should apply it to the ID of the element you want to target:

```
<div id="header">XXX</div>

#header {
    background-color: red;
    color: #000;
}
```

Remember: ID's should be unique and only apply to a single element on the page. Classes are used when you aim to target multiple elements.

If you are applying rules to a number of items you would want to use the class. There are many occasions where rules are applied similar to your second example, such as the class `clearfix` which is often found applied to a large number of elements. Others for example may be a bit unnecessary. In your first example you would have been better to target the parent wrapper, then have a rule like this:

```
.parent > div {
    min-height:335px;
}
```

At the end of the day it is often personal preference, but just remember that your code should be as tidy as possible.

One thing I always keep in mind when writing code is "*If I pass this to another developer, would they be able to understand what is going on at a glance?*"

In the case of another developer adding or changing your code **it is much easier for them to edit your CSS than it would be to edit your HTML**, which would especially be true if they were using a CMS or something which spreads code across different template files. For that reason if you begin to add `red` and `leftitems` within the HTML then the developer would have to overwrite the current rules if they decide they don't want a specific item to be red or left aligned, which can quickly get messy.

For any advanced users reading this I would recommend using SCSS rather than CSS as it can make some of the above much easier since it allows nesting and variables within your CSS - http://sass-lang.com/

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I probably really wouldn't make an id of something called `contact-me-block`. What if for some reason I want to display two of those blocks at some point for whatever reason? Basically my personal rule of thumb is use an id for structure elements (header (if not using html5), footer (if not using html5), main-content etc) when possible. My 2c

Comment: Great point. Although often unique to me, it is not a great example... Thanks for the input!

Comment: Even if the example given by OP is quite too short, the way you define your css classes and the properties you add to them technically impacts browser repaint. So saying "Technically it does not matter as both will work the same" is misleading reader as it is not true on the "Technically word", if you have heavy nested-DOM with a lot of classes. There is plenty of articles about that, for example see : http://addyosmani.com/blog/devtools-visually-re-engineering-css-for-faster-paint-times/

Answer (score 2):

I would name classes for what they represent, not for what they look like. So a class `red` is a bad idea. When you decide that all red text should actually be blue, you could end up with css like this:

```
.red {
    color: blue;
}
```

That does not make sense and actually makes styling much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't tag your CSS classes using names that suggest visual intent, like "minheightstyle". Part of the idea behind CSS is to separate content and style, a proven benefit which you attempt to invalidate with the class name(s) you display. So, this is your first rule of thumb - if you want to tag an element, you don't tag it merely for styling, you tag it taking clues from how the element is different from others with respect to its content. For example, with your three `div`s, if all are alike then it should be possible to select them as children of their parent, for instance:

```
#parent > div {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

If one of these is a selected menu item (for instance), you can give it the class "selected" and style it accordingly:

```
.selected {
    min-height: 300px; }
```

In general, try to reason about structure when designing your selectors, as opposed to thinking about style. This is perhaps a piece of advice you will discard, resorting to simpler measures, but I assure you, this is the best investment you can make if you are serious about web design today. Separation of content and style is absolutely essential, and not only just with todays HTML and CSS, it is relevant in other areas.

And second, you should remember that the rules you write are applied by the browser slavishly - i.e. the elements that end up overriden by you with your stylesheet(s), must per specification of CSS have their style recomputed from whatever it was. That is, if you (for instance) decide to override style of *all* elements with the following selector:

```
* { 
    margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

..because you decide that you are tired of the small inconsistencies between browsers applying their own little margins and paddings here and there, and you want steel control of the margins and paddings on your pages, then you should know that the browser will bind the rule above (either computing the style right then and there, or deferring it for later) to *each* element you have. Knowing this, you should reason whether it is a better idea to apply the rule above to just some elements. Same reasoning usually applies for background images - is it better to apply background color to children of an element, or simply to element itself (the result is often indistinguishable visually)?

```
 <div id="menu">
      <div>Apples</div>
      <div>Oranges</div>
      <div>Bananas</div>
 </div>
```

```
 #menu > div {
      background-color: brown;
 }
```

or

```
 #menu {
      background-color: brown;
 }
```

As to your immediate problem, a good rule of thumb is to minimize the code, including both the markup and the style. Get rid of identical class names for children, CSS is perfectly capable of selecting these without class names:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>my text in red bg</div>
    <div>my text in blue bg</div>
    <div>my text in grey bg</div>
</div>
```

```
#foo > div
{
    min-height: 300px;
    float: left;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(1)
{
    color: red;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(2)
{
    color: green;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(3)
{
    color: blue;
}
```

Of course, there are other ways to select things in the above, but just try to apply the knowledge of how CSS *really* works. Abstraction from details is a good thing, but optimization requires knowledge of said details. Try to not reason about style when designing your markup - type it as if author (your) styling will always be disabled, or type it tagging elements with content in mind. Then apply CSS, review (often one needs "wrappers", but such is web developers life these days), and repeat. But try to keep content and style separate - changing one should have minimal impact on the other.

Comment: thanks amn, this helped me a lot. one more thing I wanna ask here could you please tell me how css properties are rendered by browsers, I mean to say is how it calculates the particular style as you used parent selector to select the children div's, does it increases the rendering speed of page.

Comment: They are linked to the elements. In chains. Hence Cascading in Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). The following page will give you a great start in understanding the concept: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade Mind you, I didn't say browser have to *implement* the cascade as is, they are free to optimize their code, but the observed practice is that the implementation somehow resembles some form of cascade, i.e. things don't look much different in practice than the theoretical/abstract specification. Recognize the important practical implications, but keep theory in mind for later.

Comment: I realise your examples are meant to set people thinking, and they're not bad, but the last example doesn't make much sense in the context. The user wants to make a specific div red, based on the data in it, not on where it is in its parent. So your example falls apart when the user inserts a new div above the red one.

Comment: @MrLister It was an example on how to approach CSS efficiently. Sometimes `nth-child` is what one needs. The OP didn't say he wants to make a specific div red - they have 3 divs and want to apply colors red, blue and grey. That's part of what I wanted to convey - minimize code size and don't over-design. I don't see OP wanting a rainbow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.text {in-height:225px; float:left;}
.red{background-color:red;}
.blue{background-color:blue;}
.grey{background-color:grey;}

<div class="text red">my text in red bg</div>
<div class="text blue">my text in blue bg</div>
<div class="text grey">my text in grey bg</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if all div should have the same css style just use one class and give it to all your div if not you have to use multiple class for every div :

```
<div class="divv">afads</div>
<div class="divv">fads</div>
<div class="divv">fads</div>r code here
```

.divv{min-height:335px;}